# How do I echo previously chosen dropdown value in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, echo, edit

This code works well in terms of adding new entry with this dropdown category. My problem is, this sets Option1 as the default value to make sure the dropdown is not left unanswered. My question is, how do I echo the previously saved value for dropdown category? I should have it correctly displayed so I can do edit function correctly.

```
<tr>
    <span style="font-size: 10pt" class="label label-info">Category</span><br/>
<? $options = array
    (
        '1' => 'Option1',
        '2' => 'Option2',
        '3' => 'Option3',
        '4' => 'Option4',
    ); ?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('category_id', $options, 'Option1');?>
</tr>
```

I am looking forward to any help.

Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this works (by the way there are good classes to handle forms with codeigniter out there, where you don't have to use all this code for each field and that manage validation rules etc. in a much more flexible way - keeping the view and controller very simple and moving most of it into models).

```
<?php $model = array(
    array('value' => '1', 'display' => 'Option1'),
    array('value' => '2', 'display' => 'Option2'),
    array('value' => '3', 'display' => 'Option3'));
echo '<select name="category_id">';
foreach($model as $i) echo '<option '.($this->input->post('category_id') === $i['value'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '').' value="'.$i['value'].'">'.$i['display'].'</option>';
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Davor. Thanks for your response. I tried to write this:  <?php echo form_dropdown('category_id', $options, $_POST['category_id']);?>   But I got an error saying category_id is an undefined index..

Comment: Yes because $_POST is native PHP so if the user has not submitted the form it's not set. That's why I use the codeigniter equivalent $this->input->post which is FALSE if it doesn't exist and the post value if the form has been submitted. Using $this->input->post('category_id')!==false ? $this->input->post('category_id') : 1 you will be able to display the default option (here 1) at page load, and what the user has entered after they submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

in ref from your question : [Edit form echoes previously saved data correctly but does not update the form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850723/edit-form-echoes-previously-saved-data-correctly-but-does-not-update-the-form-fi/22855367#22855367)

```
<?php
foreach($model as $row)
{
if($row="" )
{
$selected_category_id =  '';
$options = array
(
    '1' => 'Option1',
    '2' => 'Option2',
    '3' => 'Option3',
    '4' => 'Option4',
); ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('category_id', $options, $selected_category_id);?>
}
else
{
$selected_category_id =  '$row->(database column name where vale is stored)';
$options = array
(
    '1' => 'Option1',
    '2' => 'Option2',
    '3' => 'Option3',
    '4' => 'Option4',
); ?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('category_id', $options, $selected_category_id);?>
}
}
```