# Edit form echoes previously saved data correctly but does not update the form fields

Tags: php, sql, forms, codeigniter, edit

Echoing previously saved data (excluding those from dropdown values) already works fine for me. I could see correct data saved for a particular record, however, after editing the form, I don't see anything successful after it. The data which were supposedly edited remain the same. Everything I typed to actually edit the echoed values went nowhere.

I currently have this in my controller:

```
    public function edit_job() 
{
    $this->validateRole('client');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3,0);

    $data['my_preference'] = $this->array_to_select( $this->job_model->get_all_categories(), 'id','name');
    $data['job'] = $this->job_model->get_job($id);
    $this->load->view('client/edit_job', $data);
}   

public function edit_job_submit() 
{
    $this->validateRole('client');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    if ( '0' != $_POST['id'] ) 
    {
        $this->job_model->edit_job($_POST);
    } else {
        $this->job_model->add_job($_POST);
    }
    redirect('client/manage_jobs?message=Job updated.');
}
```

While I have this in my model:

```
public function edit_job($obj)
{
    $data = array
    (
        'title' => $post_obj['title'],
        'description' => $post_obj['description'],
        'start_date' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($post_obj['start_date'])),
        'category_id' => $post_obj['category_id']
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('job', $data);    
}
```

Comment: Is it updating in the database but not updating in the view after submit...if so we may need to see your view/form code.

Comment: It does not change at all..

Comment: @kevindeleon, thanks for your reply. I have edited my question. I posted view code..

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is with this : redirect('client/manage_jobs?message=Job updated.');
instead use something like $this->load->view('success');

create a view called success and write a message saying success. put it after the update/insert function

Hope this helps

Comment: series of things like this..Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: post_obj Filename: models/job_model.php Line Number: 31

Comment: initialize the value of $post_obj first as null before using it or
use this:                                                                   
       $post_obj = array();
   foreach($query_result->result() as $row){
    $post_obj [] = $row;
     
   }
   //var_dump($post_obj );
   return $post_obj ;}

Comment: the same errors? jst var_dump the $post_obj and see what is the output... please post the $post_obj if possible

Comment: $data = array
  (
            'title' => $post_obj['title'],
            'description' => $post_obj['description'],
   'start_date' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($post_obj['start_date'])),
   'category_id' => $post_obj['category_id']
        );

Comment: in place of $post_obj as $obj and try out

Comment: It still does not change.. :(

Comment: Try this:
controller: $this->job_model->edit_job();  Model:public function edit_job()
{
    $data = array
    (
        'title' => $_POST['title'],
        'description' => $_POST['description'],
        'start_date' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($post_obj['start_date'])),
        'category_id' => $_POST['category_id']
    );

Comment: thank you so much for your help but that also does not work :((

Comment: ohhh.... then i have this last solution 
'Db_column_name'=>$this->input->post('Element_name'),
I hope this works,i use this normally

Comment: still no luck. ugh. this is exactly what made me crazy about this edit issue.. but thanks for bearing with me..

Comment: Whew! I finally had it run correctly!! Thanks for being with me on this.

Comment: I had to add $id = $obj['id']; to update particular entry attempted to be edited. :) I got some new issue though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875615/issue-in-accessing-table-contents-using-status-parameter/22876193?noredirect=1#comment34906538_22876193

Answer (score 0):

I had to add $id = $obj['id']; to update particular entry attempted to be edited