# Issue in accessing table contents using status parameter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, status

I am trying to display jobs won by a certain provider. What I did was to create function get_approved_job_proposals in my model. Then, I created function manage_job_contracts in my controller, but I never got to successfully run it.

Here's my code in model:

```
public function get_approved_job_proposals($status)
{
    $this->db->select('*')->from('job_proposal')->where('status', $status);
    $this->db->where("status" == "Awarded");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and this is what I have in my controller:

```
public function manage_job_contracts()
{
    $this->validateRole('client');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $data['my_preference'] = $this->job_model->get_approved_job_proposals($status);

    $data['job'] = $this->job_model->get_job($id);
    $this->load->view('client/manage_job_contracts', $data);
}
```

Kindly help me fix this issue.

Comment: What issue exactly, what are you expecting and what (errors...) are you getting?

Comment: Hello @jeroen, I am getting these errors:Message: Undefined variable: status as well as Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`job_proposal`) WHERE `status` IS NULL AND `0` IS NULL

Comment: I want to get the job id and provider id from this get_approved_job_proposals function I made using status parameter. My job proposal table contains job_id, provider_id and status among others.. So I wanted to access aforementioned data for me to display them in another table which I titled "Jobs won".  I added $data['job'] = $this->job_model->get_job($id); to display additional data "progress", "feedback" and "comment" which I added in my job table..

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
$this->db->where("status" == "Awarded");
```

Correct:

```
$this->db->where("status", "Awarded");
```

Check documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Thanks @FabianoAraujo, I tried to change that. But I got another issue. Undefined variable: status  as in  $data['my_preference'] = $this->job_model->get_approved_job_proposals($status);
 and Undefined variable: id  as in  $data['job'] = $this->job_model->get_job($id);

Comment: public function manage_job_contracts() <- no parameters are being received by function. Check the method signature.

Comment: do I have to put specific parameter there? manage_job_contracts should  be responsible for displaying details of job awarded by client in one new table..

Comment: Yes, indeed, but look on what your method body is calling. There is no $status and $id declared. Either those values should go as parameter, or you're missing something to define $status and $id.

Comment: I added this 
  $status = $this->db->select('status')->from('job_proposal')->where('proposal_id', $proposal_id); but got some more issues..

Comment: Sure, you're running in circles. As you're saying, $proposal isn't declared as well. Not only that, you are selecting status from job_proposal, to get * from job_proposal. Can you see how duplicated is the query?